# Magmi don't update products

Tags: magento-1.9, magmi

I'm using magmi to import in magento several product. My first import work ok, and all products were created and are visible. Now I need to update some information, like title, description and association beewtween them. I've modified my first import csv, the one that was working in the first time, then I lauch the update via ssh with the command "create" and my products are not updated. I control in frontend, backend and DB. Still old information. Do you have some ideas?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you give a proper name for attribute which you want to update in your file.

Answer (score 0):

I was using an old version of magmi with a new magento update. I've updated the last magmi version and now all work fine! Thank you!